# Angular-Material: make FAB Speed Dial overlay

Tags: css, html, material-design, angular-material

Is there a way to make the `md-fab-actions` buttons to overlay any content ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNaBPL?editors=1111

I'd like to make the width of the third column the size of only one `md-button`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set width to 0 in the md-fab-actions

```
 <md-fab-actions style="width:0px;">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXJWNw